Raspberry Pi 4 Model B shuts down when HAT is connected
I have been using the Raspberry Pi for a robotics project, and I'm using the Pimoroni Inventor HAT Mini (https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/inventor-hat-mini?variant=40588023464019) as a way to power my motors. When the Pi is on and I connect the HAT, it immediately shuts off. When I connect the HAT and then try to turn on the Pi, it refuses. Any idea what's going on?

What power supply?

I am powering it via USB-C.

I meant, are you using an official Raspberry Pi 3 Amp power supply?

Did you read this? https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=331573

Contact pimoroni. Plugging the hat in whist the Pi is powered is a bad idea - you may have damaged Pi or Hat.

Pimoroni have their own forum https://forums.pimoroni.com/

I’m voting to close this question because it's peculiar to a 3rd-party vendor's add-on hardware.
